# Accessing an object with date property

Tags: javascript

An ajax call returns a JSON array of objects containing date, hours within each date and a count for each hour. Something like:

```
jResult: 
 0: {DT: '02/28/2024', HR: '09', ERR_COUNT: 21}
 1: {DT: '02/28/2024', HR: '10', ERR_COUNT: 4}
 2: {DT: '02/28/2024', HR: '11', ERR_COUNT: 0}
....
14: {DT: '02/28/2024', HR: '23', ERR_COUNT: 25}
15: {DT: '02/29/2024', HR: '00', ERR_COUNT: 18}
16: {DT: '02/29/2024', HR: '01', ERR_COUNT: 11}
```

I needed to split this by date, in this case, end up with two arrays, one for each date. Found a post that showed how to split an array of object by property:

```
function groupBy(arr, property) {
    return arr.reduce(function (memo, x) {
        if (!memo[x[property]]) { memo[x[property]] = []; }
        memo[x[property]].push(x);
        return memo;
    }, {});
}
```

So, when I use:

```
var o = groupBy(jResult, 'DT')
```

I get an objects:

```
02/28/2024: (15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
02/29/2024: (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Stuck accessing this object. Obviously, o.02/28/2024 doesn't work and neither does o.["02/28/2024"].

How do I access each object, or maybe a better way of splitting jResul?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to access without the dot.
instead of `o.["02/28/2024"]`
use this: `o["02/28/2024"]`

Comment: Thank you. How would I traverse through each object? o.forEach(function(tbl){...}); does not seem to be correct.

Comment: never mind, had to use $.each(o, function(index, value){...});